# bridging KVM on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

So I've been trying to set up KVM on Ubuntu 18.04, with the goal being of having the vms have unique IPs on the local network (so that I can easily open up ports for them).

On OpenSUSE it did this for me, with **br0** getting it's own local IP, but when installing it on Ubuntu it instead has **virbr0** and **virbr0-nic** (and maybe also vnet0?), which uses it's own internal IP.

And from what I gather from this tutorial: [url](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-kvm-ubuntu-18-04-server/)

I need to create my own **br0** which will get a LAN ip and at the same time no IP on the real NIC (**enp0**), then how exactly am I going to connect to the kvm host?

My closest guess would be it'll be something like this:

```
KVM host IP ----
                |----br0 ---- network
                |
VM IP ----------
```

But then what's the use for **virbr0**?

Comment: for what you are wanting, there is no use at all for virbr0. If you do things with a virtual network instead, then virbro would be used.

Comment: I see, is my assumption correct about how the network would be setup with br0?

Comment: Yes. see also [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html.en-CA#bridging).

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, Dough manage to help me out,

virbr0 isn't needed and my assumption about br0 turned out to be correct (after reading the guide it showed it was a static IP),

So essentially br0 will have that static IP for the kvm-host and the rest will be for the kvm-guest.